# Allow for a jekyll post to have no day only year and month

Tags: jekyll

Sometimes I have projects that I launch and it takes a month of work and they're launched within a month they have no specific date associated with them. I would like to save a post something like `2011-05-00noday.md` but jekyll will not allow it. Is there any way to do this and have the permalink reflect `/2011/05/noday.html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this setting for YAML config file:

```
#for all pages
permalink: pretty

#for posts
defaults:
  - scope:
     path: ""
     type: "posts"
    values:
#this looks prettier
     permalink: /blog/:title
#for your needs
     permalink: /:year/:month/:title
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like that should be a `page` not a `post`. You could have a root level folder called `/projects/`, then inside that have either an individual file for each project or a sub directory for each project with an `index.md` file inside it.

If you don't like that idea, you can set the `permalink` in the `YAML Front Matter` of a `post` and that will override the setting from _config.yml:

```
---
layout: post
permalink: /projects/project_name/
---
```

or if you want the date in there and don't want **all** your permalinks to be set this way:

```
---
layout: post
permalink: /:year/:month/:title.html
(replace with actual year, month and title, e.g., /2013/06/my-title.html)
---
```

See the way they do projects in this Jekyll site:
https://github.com/flatterline/flatterline.com/tree/master/_projects

Comment: The ymlfm variables for :year :month and :title don't work it set the permalink to the literal `http://localhost:1111/:year/:month/:title.html`.

Comment: @ThomasReggi, yes, those are placeholders you would replace with the literal date. I'll update that with a note.